# Is there a system that converts C# Models into knockout objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've been tasked with adding a feature to an app written by someone who has since left my company. This is implemented with C#/Knockout/Breeze/Durandal. I'm wondering if anyone can answer some of the questions I have regarding the inner workings of knockout and C# interactions:

1) Why is knockout converting an existing ICollection to an observableArray properly, but not a new one that I've added to the model?

2) What is the mechanism that converts the Model to obs/obsArrays? I'm guessing it's got something to do with how the data is pulled back but I'm not sure.

I do not see any js code that would initialize the existing Collection as an observableArray, there's no

```
vm.existingCollection = ko.observableArray();
```

He just uses it in is source code as

```
vm.existingCollection.push(stuff);
```

**Edit to include some code for reference**

Here's the model code I'm working with:

```
public class SimCompare : Report
    {
        public string LeftGraphName { get; set; }
        public int? LeftConsolidationId { get; set; }
        public int LeftAsOfDateOffset { get; set; }
        public int LeftSimCompareSimulationTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Consolidation LeftConsolidation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SimCompareSimulationType> LeftSimCompareSimulationTypes { get; set; }


        public string RightGraphName { get; set; }
        public int? RightConsolidationId { get; set; }
        public int RightAsOfDateOffset { get; set; }
        public int RightSimCompareSimulationTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Consolidation RightConsolidation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SimCompareSimulationType> RightSimCompareSimulationTypes { get; set; }

        public bool IsQuarterly { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SimCompareScenarioType> SimCompareScenarioTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

Then there's a simcompareconfig.js file that starts off like this:

```
define([
    'services/globalcontext',
    'viewmodels/simulationselectconfig',
    'durandal/app'
],
    function (globalContext, simulationselectconfig, app) {

        var simCompareVm = function (simCompare) {
            var self = this;
            this.simCompare = simCompare;
```

...

There is an existing function to add a scenarioType with a line that looks like this:

```
simCompare().simCompareScenarioTypes().push(newSimCompareScenarioType);
```

But that simCompareScenarioTypes() isn't defined anywhere in terms of JS (that I can see). However there is a similar definition in the C# model. This is what's leading me to believe that the model is somehow getting mapped behind the scenes.

Any help is greeeeatly appreciated.

Comment: Tool-down and take a moment to work through the tutorial... http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: We would need to see the code you've tried so far. Otherwise it's quite hard to figure out what specifically is your question.

Comment: The title suggests to me that the KO.Mapping plugin (with an Ajax call) is what you're after. Return your C# Model as JSON to a KO ViewModel and the mapping plugin will "convert" all the C# properties to KO observables and observableArrays. You might want to break this question out into a couple questions. I got a little lost